# Permission denied from a subfolder

Tags: php, iis, windows-11

## Context

- PHP 5.6
- IIS
- Windows 11

## Issue

I am trying to write a file in a specific folder but it gives me `permission denied`.
So, I verified the permissions and everything seemed all right. Because this is in a development environment, I decided to change the permissions to be "Every one can do anything" to the "root" folder where all my files are written. I tried to replace all the permissions underneath. I tried to remove the inherited permissions. Nothing does it.

I then tried to write a file in the "root" folder. It worked.On the subfolder, it worked. On the subsubfolder. It worked. In the subfolder chain there is a point when it doesn't work, but before the real subfolder.

Here is the path hierachy when it crashes.

```
$f = new \wee\common\IO\File();
$f->write("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/00.jpg", "hello"); // WORKS
$f->write("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/00.jpg", "hello"); // WORKS
$f->write("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/com.ci.company/00.jpg", "hello"); // WORKS
$pathLength = strlen("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/com.ci.company/site/00.jpg"); // Real path length is 85
$f->write("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/com.ci.company/site/00.jpg", "hello"); // FAILS
$f->write("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/com.ci.company/site/WorkersManager/00.jpg", "hello");
$f->write("DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/com.ci.company/site/WorkersManager/workers/00.jpg", "hello");
```

The class `\wee\common\IO\File` is my creation, but works at a lot of other places.

The exact error message I am getting is:

`fopen(DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/-/mod/com.ci.company/site/00.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Just to be 100% clear: The "root" folder is `DRIVE:/BASE_PATH/files/`

## Edit #1

Here is the implementation of the `write` method of the `File` class.

```
public function write($fileName, $data, $lock = false) {
    $this->_write($fileName, $data, $lock);
}

private function _write($fileName, $data, $lock = false, $openMode = 'w') {
    if ($data === null)
        $data = "";
    
    $fh = fopen($fileName, $openMode) or die("can't open file"); // FAILS HERE
    if ($lock) {
        flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
    }
    fwrite($fh, (is_array($data) ? join("\n", $data) : $data));
    if ($lock) {
        fflush($fh);
        flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Check if there is a *file* called "site", where you expect the folder to be.

Comment: "I decided to change the permissions to be "Every one can do anything" to the "root" folder" - this is a terrible idea, even on a dev machine. You only need to change permissions of the folders in the path. Check each individual folder mentioned and make sure the user Php runs has read access on all folders on the path and read&write access on just the folders where php needs to write files("least privilege"). As @astax points out the `site` folder probably has some permissions overriding the "everone" further up the path.

Comment: @astax There is no file called "site". The folder already exists.

Comment: @MisterSmith I know it is a bad idea to have those kind of permissions, but when you want to be sure the problem is not that, this shall ensure it. The `site` folder has the same permission as the "root" folder because has told, I replaced / override all subfolders/files permissions from "root".

Comment: You can try giving `IUSR` full control permissions.

Comment: @samwu Still not fixing it.

Comment: Have you actually checked the site folder - just because you tell it to update all permissions doesnt mean it actually does, especially if there are any "weird" permissions anywhere in the path it can go "wonky".  Also, from php output `get_current_user()` - that should tell you the username of Php thats trying to the write the files - thats the user you need to add. If your positive the folder permissions are correct, is there some php.ini values causing it to fail etc? Without visibility into the code generating your output or the ACL's on the folders all we can do is guess. Good luck!

Comment: @MisterSmith I had already checked the permissions on the `site` folder and it is the same as its parents upto the "root"/"files" folder. Using `get_current_user()` gives me `IUSR` and it is included in the ACL's of the `site` folder. When you are talking about the code generating the output, you mean the `write` method of the `File` class?

Comment: @MisterSmith In advance, I added the `File::write` method in the question description.

Comment: Running out of ideas - seems like it should work. Could try creating a new folder `testsite` inside `com.ci.company` and see if that works - tests if its related to path length/number of subfolders? Did you check the php.ini (or maybe use `php_info()`) - could be some setting issue (esp as its a dev machine). Your version of Php is 3 major versions old - is there any related bugs? Last resort - spin up a temp VM/cloud server and try this on another machine - could just be a gremlin in the server ;-)

Comment: @MisterSmith I tried PHP 7.1.13 and it works. Definitively, it is an "inside" bug. I will try PHP 5.6.40 as I were using 5.6.26. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: @MisterSmith Problem fixed with 5.6.40. Damn. I thought there were no new PHP 5.6 versions so I didn't verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from PHP 5.6.26. Using PHP 5.6.40 fixed it.

I reset to my original permissions and everything is fine!